# Fabric BETA adds TwitterAdvertisingInfoPreferences the app's data

Tags: android, android-sharedpreferences, crashlytics-android, crashlytics-beta

We're using Fabric Crashlytics with BETA for distribution of our builds and we noticed that it adds certain set of unwanted preferences to app data. One of them is called 'TwitterAdvertisingInfoPreferences' which doesn't seem to be useful for our usage and may become a privacy issue. How can we prevent Crashlytics from adding it?

Answer (score 5):

Mike from Fabric here.

That preference is added when an app starts using Fabric and is one of the identifiers used to help uniquely identify devices to give accurate counts of the number of users affected by crashes. Fabric completely respects the limit ad tracking features on both iOS and Android so if a user reset their advertising identifier then they would be treated as a new user for Crashlytics or Answers.

Comment: why you guys named it as "Twitter"?

Comment: Fabric was owned by Twitter previously.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to write your own random value to advertising_id in that shared preference in order to block the tracking. I don't know if that would violate Fabric's terms of use.